# Add a custom property to the Sitecore services client api call results

Tags: sitecore-services-client

I have a requirement to get the full presentation details (layout field + final layout field) using Sitecore services client api call. Now i am receiving the results as two different property fields (__Renderings and __Final Renderings). I need to create a custom property so that i can show the merged value of both Rendering and Final Rendering value. Is there any way we can create and show custom property using ssc api call.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? http://www.mikerobbins.co.uk/sitecore/sitecore.services.client/2015/03/20/sitecore-entity-service-ssc-custom-controller-action.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "full" final layout xml (merged deltas with shared layout) using following code snippet:

```
var item = Sitecore.Context.Item;
var finalLayoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.FinalLayoutField]);
var finalLayoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(finalLayoutField.Value);
var xml = finalLayoutDefinition.ToXml();
```